# 10BASE-T over Analog Speaker Cabling

Tags: ethernet

I have 16 AWG shielded twisted pair cables in my building (West Penn stranded 16AWG twisted pair). Can I run 10BASE-T over these wires?

Comment: yes you can but it might be a lot harder to get it to reliably work than proper cable. Google transmission lines and terminations. Be prepared to not understand the answers you get for at least a day.

Comment: looks like it might be  `West Penn 225`. I can't find figures for the characteristic impedance of that cable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, maybe. It all depends on the wire.

1) You'll need 2 pairs to run 10BaseT.
2) You'll need the right impedance. Get a tester, or find the characteristics of the cables and compare them with the 10BaseT spec.
3) Normal Ethernet cables are about 24 ga. Making a connection from 16 AWG to an RJ45 will be tedious, at best.

Overall, I'm sure you can use your cable, but installing connectors will be a pain in the butt, and there is no guarantee what sort of length you'll be able to use.

Comment: RJ45 sockets are available with screw terminals they probably won't work with 100base-T but 10base-T could be ok.

Comment: Punch-down sockets *might* work, but the wire thickness may mean that you'd have to replace them if you get the correct cable in place.